# librdkafka c++ API custom logger function

Tags: c++, logging, apache-kafka

I'm using the librdkafka c++ API and I would like to change the default behavior of the logger (default to stderr).

It is listed in the configuration documentation that I can change the log_cb function but I can't find how to do this in the c++ API.

In the c API there is this function rd_kafka_conf_set_log_cb() to set the log callback.

In addition, I would like to be able to change the log severity level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The librdkafka C++ API exposes logs, stats, throttling, etc, through a generic Event type.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.cpp#L91) how to use it.
Excerpt:

```
class ExampleEventCb : public RdKafka::EventCb {
 public:
  void event_cb (RdKafka::Event &event) {
    switch (event.type())
    {
      case RdKafka::Event::EVENT_LOG:
        fprintf(stderr, "LOG-%i-%s: %s\n",
                event.severity(), event.fac().c_str(), event.str().c_str());
        break;

      default:
    }
  }
};

...

ExampleEventCb ex_event_cb;
conf->set("event_cb", &ex_event_cb, errstr);
```

As for the log level/severity: You can configure the `log_level` to suppress log messages with a higher level (less important).